# onclick vs. onfocus - Input text select behaviour differs. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onfocus

I see that when I select text in a text-box with the help of 'onfocus' function, I don't get the behaviour I expect.

Here is the demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/BquZz/

A copy of the code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select all</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text;
var log;

function select()
{
    text.select();
    log.innerHTML += ' - select';
}

window.onload = function() {
    text = document.getElementById('text');
    log = document.getElementById('log');
    log.innerHTML = 'start';

    text.onfocus = select;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="text" readonly="readonly" value="hello, world">
<div id="log">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I repeat the following experiment multiple times.

1. Click somewhere outside the text-box in order to blur the text-box.
2. Click on the text-box in order to focus the text-box.

I expect that every time at the end of step 2, the string "hello, world" in the text-box should be selected. However, this is not what I observe. With Iceweasel 11.0 on Debian GNU/Linux (Wheezy), at the end of alternate experiments "hello, world" is not selected. In the remaining experiments, sometimes I see the string "hello, world" completely selected and sometimes, partially selected. With Chrome 18.0.1025.33 beta on Debian GNU/Linux (Wheezy), I rarely get the desired result. Most of the times, nothing is selected.

I know a way to fix this. Change `text.onfocus = select` to `text.onclick = select`. With the `select()` function invoked with `onclick`, I get the expected result. Here is a demo URL which shows the desired result using 'onclick': http://jsfiddle.net/5EZwR/

Could you please help me to understand why I do not get the expected result with 'onfocus' but I get it with 'onclick'?

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281960/how-to-highlight-input-text-field-upon-clicking-it-in-safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `.select()` does **two** things: it sets the selection range to include all the text, **and** it causes the field to be focused.  The browsers appear to dislike the repeated selection, though Chrome and Firefox behave differently.

If you change it to:

```
text.setSelectionRange(0, 10000);
```

then it works in Firefox. (I think it'd have to be different for Internet Explorer.)

*edit* — [This Stackoverflow question](http://goo.gl/DsGX5) has a good answer (Mr. Dimitrov's) that should work for all browsers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I decided to see whether `.select()` causes the input text element's `.onfocus` method to be called. With http://jsfiddle.net/WvBAq/ I find that it gets called on Iceweasel but not on Chrome.

Comment: `text.setSelectionRange(0, 10000);` doesn't seem to work for me on either IceWeasel or Chrome. Here is the demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/pBAKx/

Comment: Hmm well there may be some other API for the WebKit browsers. That function exists in Firefox.  I'll see what I can find.